# Releases stuck in 'Rejected' state

Tags: ms-release-management

I wanted to delete an old release template we used for testing to clean up Release Management a bit. But when I tried to deactivate the template, I got the following message:

> To deactivate this release template, any releases that use this
>   template must have one of the following statuses: Released, Abandoned

[image: Release Deactivation Warning]

Alright, that message makes sense... there must be a few unfinished releases that I need to finish, either by completing the process or abandoning it. When I went to the list of pending releases though, there are a bunch of them in the `Rejected` state that I can neither retry nor abandon. For example:

[image: Can't abandon/continue Release]

Now I can't delete the old, obsolete template, because I can't find a way to abandon these rejected releases. What should I do to delete the template?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the rights? Can you try with a Release Manager user and see if you can abandon it?

Comment: @joerage My user is a release manager (I have full rights on the client).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are or are in the group that is responsible for the Validation of the stage.

I had a similar issue even though I am a Release Manager, but when I made myself the Validator of the stage that it failed/rejected on, it allowed me to access the Retry/Restart/Abandon buttons for the rejected releases.

*Configure Paths / Release Paths / [Path name]:*

[image: Release Path / Stage Configuration]

This can get out of sync if you have a domain username change like I did. It hadn't propagated all the way through our system yet, so the Release Administration group didn't include my new guid.  So I assigned my new User to the Validator role and the buttons appeared on the Release window.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long to get back to you about this... I read it at the time but didn't have time to comment on it, and then later on I completely forgot about it. Anyways... this does not work in my case. I have the 'Release Managers' group set as the validator for all stages, and it still does not work. Keep in mind that this works for some releases and not for others, using the same path and template.