# How to batch update releases in TFS Release Management

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

Does anyone know how to batch update releases in Release Management through the Release Management client or command line? There's a bunch of releases that we'd like to Abandon but it seems that it requires us doing it one at a time. I'm sure there's a way for me to do this within the Release Management database but I'd rather not muck around in there if I don't have to!

Of course I'd prefer to [delete theses releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873141/how-do-we-delete-a-release-in-tfs-2013-release-management) but until that ability is enabled for releases not in Draft, I'll have to stick w/ Abandon. Or go into the database a manually delete them there (at my own risk of course).

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If you edit the database directly you are forgoing all future support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using the client.

Using releases for Agent-based deployment, the only option you have is through the db.

For vNext releases, there might be a way with REST calls, but not sure about that one. I will try to look it up.