# MS Release management clean up of drop folders

Tags: ms-release-management

We have four stages in our release path (DEV, TEST, UAT and PROD) and I had been planning on using the validation step on DEV as a release to TEST gateway. If the developers think that it's worth the test team looking at a build they approve it otherwise they reject it (with different approvers on the other stages).

I'm looking to get some sort of clean up running on the build drop folder for builds that have been rejected (or abandonded). Either by deleting them or by changing the keep indefinitely flag on the TFS build.

Is there anyway to do this manually (or better yet automatically?)

I suspect it could be done by querying the RM database and calling the TFS api but I'd like to save the effort of doing this myself.

Meant to say that this is partially covered here (with a "no"):

[How do we delete a release in TFS 2013 Release Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873141/how-do-we-delete-a-release-in-tfs-2013-release-management)

But it's only really the drop folder I care about not the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is still basically "no". It's clear you already get how all of the pieces work -- the retain indefinitely flag is set when a release starts, and it's up to you to manually clear it if you don't want the build to be retained.

That said, it really *should* be a configurable option. It just isn't.