# How to keep MS Release Management clean

Tags: database, ms-release-management

Does anyone have experience with keeping the MS Release Management database clean? I really like to cleanup old releases. I do not need any information about releases that gone wrong a couple of months ago.

And I think it will boost the client if i keep the database cleaner...

Edit:
I'm not asking for an opinion, i'm asking if someone has some cleaning sql statements for me to keep the database more cleaner. Before I start trying it on my own....

Edit: 
It was stated that the answer could be found in another question: [How do we delete a release in TFS 2013 Release Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873141). But the answer cannot be found in this thread. Only that it is not possible with the client of Release Management to remove (old) releases.

Off course we can remove releases by removing records in the database directly. I found out that our Release Management Clients are very slowly, and if i use an 'clean' database (on our acceptance machine) the client is faster when the database is smaller.

So my problem is that working with Release Management Client is very slow. And the database is full of releases that i do not need to keep. Also as an administrator we like to keep databases clean. SO the question remains, does anyone have experience manually (sql-queries) cleaning the Release Management Database.

Comment: No way Mohit Kanwar. Just want to know if someone has queries or something to keep it clean.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we delete a release in TFS 2013 Release Management?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873141/how-do-we-delete-a-release-in-tfs-2013-release-management)

Comment: Check that other question and look at the comments of first answer for possible query to achieve deletion of releases.

Comment: Dennis what is the problem that you are trying to fix? What if deleting the releases doesn't speed up the client?