# Release in Progress while in Abandoned and Cancelled state - Release Management

Tags: deployment, release-management, ms-release-management

I have a problem in Release Management 2013. A release was failing in its deploy actions, so it was stopped, giving it status Cancelled. Then the release was abandoned. However, still two action are still In Progress, after two days now. I have full rights to edit and manage all parts of this release, but now unable to stop, delete or retry this release.

[image]

New releases for the same target server give the following error:

> New deployment is not allowed as another deployment is in progress.
>   Retry the deployment after sometime.

Release Management Monitor service was restarted but this didn't help.
Release are based on vNext templates

Anybody idea how to resolve this?

Comment: According to joerage's reply in this case, only Releases in Draft state can be deleted. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873141/how-do-we-delete-a-release-in-tfs-2013-release-management

Comment: Yes I saw this, but that's not an option here. Now looking at editing the RM database, which is not desired of course, but maybe the only option?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to force reject a run-away release in Release Management 2015.